# Hacer que los valores converjan hacia el minimo valor en una serie de datos

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Tengo el siguiente codigo para generar una matriz:

```
import numpy as np

dimension = 2
tamaño = 8
decrement = 0.9
matriz = np.asarray([np.random.random(dimension) for _ in range(tamaño)])
print(matriz)
minimo = np.amin(matriz[:,0])

for _ in range(100):
  #Es aqui donde graduaremos exponencialmente los valores
```

Tengo una matriz de tamaño 2x8
Paso seguido identificio el valor minimo en la columna "[0]", con el fin de crear un bucle de ***N*** iteraciones para hacer que en cada una de ellas los demas elementos vayan convergiendo a ese el valor minimo
Pero el asunto es que para que converjan de manera "gradual" el valor de la variable decremento no tendria que ser el mismo para todos y es allí donde viene mi pregunta
¿Que tendria que hacer para en cada iteracion ir modificando el valor de la variable "Decrement"" A tal punto que cuando se llegue a las ultimas iteraciones haya una desviacion estandar minima

Psdt:
Encontre esto en SO espero sea de ayuda

[numpy / scipy: Making one series converge towards another after a period of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34141798/numpy-scipy-making-one-series-converge-towards-another-after-a-period-of-time)

### **Ejemplo**

```
[[0.90853515 0.62336012]
 [0.01582124 0.92943723]
 [0.69089692 0.99732285]
 [0.17234051 0.13713575]
 [0.93259546 0.69681816]
 [0.06600017 0.75546305]
 [0.75387619 0.92302454]
 [0.71152476 0.12427096]]
```

Como podemos observar el minimo valor de esa matriz seria:

```
0.015821242846556283
```

Lo que tenemos que proceder a hacer es autoajustar los demas valores en cada iteración minimamente con tal que vayan convergiendo al minimo al final la columna en la cual estamos ajustando podria verse asi:

```
  [0.01592127
  0.01589542
  0.015826342
  0.01534542
  0.01582452
  0.015834542
  0.0158456
  0.01582435]
```

### Nota:

No tienen que converger perfectamente despues que sus 2 o 3 primeras cifras sean iguales no importan tanto las demas cabe resaltar que tienen que converger de manera gradual.

Comment: Falta un ejemplo con la matriz generada y cual sería el resultado correcto,

Comment: Sii, se me olvido anexarlo

Answer (score 3):

En lugar de usar un solo valor como decremento, podemos usar un vector que de el decremento para cada fila de la matriz.

Luego de formar la matriz y determinar el mínimo de la columna cero, formamos un vector con la diferencia de cada elemento respecto al mínimo, divida por el número de pasos, que sería 100.

Luego iteremos, restando en cada ciclo el vector a la columna.

En resumen, es un decrecimiento lineal.

```
dimension = 2
tamaño = 8
matriz = np.asarray([np.random.random(dimension) for _ in range(tamaño)])
minimo = np.amin(matriz[:,0])
print("Matriz original")
print("---------------")
print(matriz)
print()
print(f"Minimo: {minimo}")

diff = np.array([(x[0] - minimo) / 100 for x in matriz])
print("Vector ajuste")
print(diff)
    
for i in range(100):
    matriz[0:,0] = matriz[0:,0] - diff
    print()
    print(f"Iteracion {i + 1}")
    print(matriz)
```

produce:

```
Matriz original
---------------
[[0.14708829 0.12575646]
 [0.731613   0.43997723]
 [0.20826289 0.60077955]
 [0.17234684 0.57230083]
 [0.25113622 0.66459213]
 [0.55850112 0.46812995]
 [0.45864303 0.30966853]
 [0.46478251 0.24286022]]

Minimo: 0.14708828960197318
Vector ajuste
[0.         0.00584525 0.00061175 0.00025259 0.00104048 0.00411413
 0.00311555 0.00317694]

Iteracion 1
[[0.14708829 0.12575646]
 [0.72576776 0.43997723]
 [0.20765114 0.60077955]
 [0.17209426 0.57230083]
 [0.25009574 0.66459213]
 [0.55438699 0.46812995]
 [0.45552749 0.30966853]
 [0.46160556 0.24286022]]

Iteracion 2
[[0.14708829 0.12575646]
 [0.71992251 0.43997723]
 [0.2070394  0.60077955]
 [0.17184167 0.57230083]
 [0.24905527 0.66459213]
 [0.55027286 0.46812995]
 [0.45241194 0.30966853]
 [0.45842862 0.24286022]]

Iteracion 3
[[0.14708829 0.12575646]
 [0.71407726 0.43997723]
 [0.20642765 0.60077955]
 [0.17158909 0.57230083]
 [0.24801479 0.66459213]
 [0.54615874 0.46812995]
 [0.44929639 0.30966853]
 [0.45525168 0.24286022]]

...........

Iteracion 99
[[0.14708829 0.12575646]
 [0.15293354 0.43997723]
 [0.14770004 0.60077955]
 [0.14734088 0.57230083]
 [0.14812877 0.66459213]
 [0.15120242 0.46812995]
 [0.15020384 0.30966853]
 [0.15026523 0.24286022]]

Iteracion 100
[[0.14708829 0.12575646]
 [0.14708829 0.43997723]
 [0.14708829 0.60077955]
 [0.14708829 0.57230083]
 [0.14708829 0.66459213]
 [0.14708829 0.46812995]
 [0.14708829 0.30966853]
 [0.14708829 0.24286022]]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta! Más sin embargo me quedo la duda de como hacerlo de manera exponencial.

Comment: Estaba pensando en ello. Mañana a ver si me animo.

Comment: Pienso que si se hace una manera de tipo exponencial se evitaria calcular un vector de decremento ¿Crees que es posible?

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que la función exponencial es de esta forma:

```
f(x) = a * b^x
```

Además tú tienes 2 puntos inicial y final (xi,yi) y (xf,yf), donde:

- xi = 0
- xf = 100
- yi = Es el punto de tu array
- yf = Es el punto final, es decir el mínimo del array

Reemplazando en la formula anterior:

```
yi = a * b^x = a * b^0 => yi = a
yf = a * b^100 =>  yf / a = b^100 => yf/yi = b^100 => b = pow( yf/yi, 1/ (100-1))
```

Por ejemplo tenemos el siguiente array:

```
matriz =[0.90853515 ,0.01582124 ,0.69089692,0.17234051,0.93259546 ,0.06600017 ,0.75387619,0.71152476 ]
```

Será entonces, para el primer punto (0.90853515):

```
xi = 0
xf = 100
yi = 0.90853515
yf = 0.01582124 #El mínimo

a = 0.90853515
b = pow( 0.01582124 / 0.90853515 , 1/99) =  0,959911734689036

f(x) = 0.90853515 * 0,959911734689036^x  #funcion decremento
```

En palabras simples la función decremento `a * b^x`

- a es el valor del punto
- b hay que calcularlo (a partir de `a`, el mínimo y la cantidad de iteraciones)
- x es el valor de `i` en cada iteración

---

Ahora yo de python ni idea, pero supongo que algo así podría ser:

```
import numpy as np

dimension = 2
tamaño = 8
decrement = 0.9
matriz = np.asarray([np.random.random(dimension) for _ in range(tamaño)])
print(matriz)
minimo = np.amin(matriz[:,0])

N = 100 #iteraciones

def getB(xi,xf,Cant): #obtiene b
    couc = xf / xi
    exp = 1 / (Cant-1)
    return pow(couc,exp)

for i in range(N):
    for j in range(size):
        y = matriz[j][0] * pow( getB(matriz[j][0],minimo,N),i) #a * b^x 
    print("==============================")
```

Answer (score -1):

Reduciendo el valor de "decrement" en cada iteración del bucle, lo que estamos haciendo es ir aumentando la velocidad a la que se van actualizando los valores de la matriz para que converjan hacia el mínimo. Esto hará que, en las últimas iteraciones del bucle, los valores de la matriz se actualicen más rápidamente, lo que hará que la desviación estándar entre ellos sea menor.

Sin embargo, reducir el valor de "decrement" no garantiza que la desviación estándar sea mínima en las últimas iteraciones del bucle. Para lograr eso, tendrías que calcular la desviación estándar en cada iteración del bucle, y comprobar si ha disminuido respecto a la iteración anterior. Si ha disminuido, entonces puedes seguir reduciendo el valor de "decrement" en cada iteración para acelerar aún más la convergencia de los valores hacia el mínimo. Si, en cambio, la desviación estándar no ha disminuido, entonces puedes aumentar el valor de "decrement" para reducir la velocidad a la que se actualizan los valores de la matriz, lo que permitirá aumentar la precisión de la convergencia hacia el mínimo.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de cómo podrías hacer esto:

```
import numpy as np

def decremento(iteracion, valor_actual, valor_minimo):
  # Calcular el decremento inicial
  decremento = 1.0 - (iteracion / 100.0)

  # Aumentar el decremento si el valor actual está cerca del valor mínimo
  if abs(valor_actual - valor_minimo) < 0.001:
    decremento *= 10

  return decremento

# Crear una matriz de ejemplo
matrix = np.array([[0.90853515, 0.62336012],
                    [0.01582124, 0.92943723],
                    [0.69089692, 0.99732285],
                    [0.17234051, 0.13713575],
                    [0.93259546, 0.69681816],
                    [0.06600017, 0.75546305],
                    [0.75387619, 0.92302454],
                    [0.71152476, 0.12427096]])

# Identificar el valor mínimo en la primera columna
valor_minimo = matrix[:, 0].min()

# Realizar 100 iteraciones para ajustar los elementos de la matriz
for i in range(100):
  # Recorrer cada elemento de la matriz y ajustar su valor
  for j in range(matrix.shape[0]):
    # Calcular el decremento para este elemento en esta iteración
    dec = decremento(i, matrix[j, 0], valor_minimo)

    # Ajustar el valor del elemento
    matrix[j, 0] = np.maximum(matrix[j, 0] - dec, valor_minimo)

# Imprimir la matriz resultante
print(matrix)
```

En este código, en cada iteración del bucle se actualiza el valor de "decrement" en función de la precisión de la convergencia hacia el mínimo. De esta manera, en las últimas iteraciones del bucle la desviación estándar debería ser mínima, ya que estamos ajustando el valor de "decrement" en función de la precisión de la convergencia hacia el mínimo.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver tu problema.

Comment: Cual seria el codigo al que te refieres cuando dices "Aqui iria el codigo para hacer que los valores converjan......."

Comment: Edité el código

Comment: Probe el codigo pero las columnas soluciones dan valores mucho mas pequeños que el vector minimo, valores por ejemplo 0.000015... creo que hay un error en la logica

Comment: Nueva edición, todos los valores llegan al mínimo 0.01582124, puedes probarlo aquí https://onecompiler.com/python/3yqtgfhqu no había visto que agregaste una matriz de ejemplo